# Highlighting a row when a dropdown option is selected

Tags: list-view, issue-tracking

I was wondering how to highlight a whole row (just the background) red only when a dropdown option labeled `(archive)` in a column labeled `(Status)` is selected?

Can this be done using a web part or using a calculated column?

P.S. I do not have site collection privileges.

Comment: Office 365. I get a message saying "only secure content is displayed." I added the script editor web part and copy and pasted the code in edit snippet.

Comment: Do I have to upload the jquery to my style library?

Comment: "only secure content is displayed" require https reference so try to use **https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js** with https

Comment: It still didn't work.

Comment: What about using an IF statement or changing the background with a calculated column such as style=’width:150px; height:20px; background-color:”&CHOOSE(LEFT(Status,1), “green”, “orange”, “red”, “purple”)&”;’?

Comment: please join me at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61307/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-vier111

Comment: I did get this error message when I tried another code: 
TypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined   or null referenceTypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or   null reference 
 
TypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null referenceTypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null referenceTypeError: Unable to get property '_events' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try to do the following:**

- Edit your All Items page.
- Add script editor web part.
- add the below script

  ```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js">
  </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){     
      $Text = $("td .ms-vb2:contains('archive')");
      $Text.parent().css("background-color", "Red");
  }); 
  </script>
  ```

**[OutPut]**

[image]

**Note:**

- The `Status field` should be shown in your view
- If your server is not connected to the internet, try to download the jquery and upload it to your `style library` then reference it to your script.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61308/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-highlighting-a-row-when-a-dropdown-option-is-se).